# What is the A* algorithm in case the heuristic function H is not monotonic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star, heuristics

I've tried to figure what the A* algorithm would be in case the Heuristic function would not satisfy the monotonicity condition, where in

**h(u) <= e(u,v) + h(v), for every u,v such that there is an edge between u and v**

is the condition for monotonicity, where h is the heuristic function, u and v are vertices in the search graph, and the function e gives the edge cost between u and v (The search graph is undirected). However, wikipedia   (here)   does not give the algorithm for this, nor do other sources like Norvig's book on Artificial Intelligence.

Is there a good source to study this. Pseudo code would be great!

Also, I do not wish to solve this by converting the non monotonic heuristic function to a heuristic one.

Comment: I have no idea who suggested the closevote, but this is not an offtopic question.

Comment: I've got a problem understanding the type of answer expected. "Slower"  looks like it's a valid answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand the algorithm that would work in the said case. For now, I am not worried about the time complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the heuristic function function is still [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) - A* algorithm will work fine.

However, for non-monotonic heuristic functions, you might need to update an already 'closed' node, and you should allow this behavior.

Comment: The thing is, do we not have to also update the children of those guys that we update in the closed list?

Comment: @ashu You will need to treat this node like any other node you just 'discover', including re-opening closed descendent if the new price is better then the already found one.

Comment: And I should do this recursively right (for the children which are updated in the closed list)?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of **tree search** it's not required to be consistent to be optimal. Instead if it's a **graph search** A* is optimal only in the case that the heuristic is admissible and consistent.

In this picture you can see an example of a non consistent heuristic: the A* algorithm doesn't find the right path.

[image: example]

Maybe you can modify the standard A* algorithm as @amit said, but in that case you need to consider an already closed state, so the search will not be optimal. It may find the optimal path but it will expand more nodes than in the solution with a consistent heuristic, so it'll be sub-optimal.

Comment: I think that this would depend on what you consider to be the "standard A* algorithm". Personally I would consider the algorithm that allows the updating of closed nodes to be the standard algorithm, and the one that relies on a monotonic heuristic to be a special case (albeit a common special case) of A*. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) article is always careful to mention if it is referring to A* in general or A* with the assumption of a monotonic heuristic.